# Simple Ray Tracing with Lambertian Shading, Confusion

Tags: c++, raytracing, shading

I didn't see another post with a problem similar to mine, so hopefully this is not redundant.

I've been reading a book on the fundamentals of computer graphics (third edition) and I've been implementing a basic ray tracing program based on the principles I've learned from it. I had little trouble implementing parallel and perspective projection but after moving onto Lambertian and Blinn-Phong Shading I've run into a snag that I'm having trouble figuring out on my own.

I believe my problem is related to how I am calculating the ray-sphere intersection point and the vectors to the camera/light. I attached a picture that is output when I run simply perspective projection with no shading.

[Perspective Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHl32.png)

However, when I attempt the same scene with Lambertian shading the spheres disappear.

[Blank Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LbbS.png)

While trying to debug this myself I noticed that if I negate the x, y, z coordinates calculated as the hit point, the spheres appear again. And I believe the light is coming from the opposite direction I expect.

[Lambertian, negated hitPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fLqB.png)

I am calculating the hit point by adding the product of the projected direction vector and the *t* value, calculated by the ray-sphere intersection formula, to the origin (where my "camera" is, 0,0,0) or just *e + td*.

The vector from the hit point to the light, *l*, I am setting to the light's position minus the hit point's position (so hit point's coords minus light's coords).

*v*, the vector from the hit point to the camera, I am getting by simply negating the projected view vector;

And the surface normal I am getting by hit point minus the sphere's position.

All of which I believe is correct. However, while stepping through the part that calculates the surface normal, I notice something I think is odd. When subtracting the hit point's position from the sphere's position to get the vector from the sphere's center to the hit point, I believe I should expect to get a vector where all of the values lie within the range (-r,r); but that is not happening.

This is an example from stepping through my code:
Calculated hit point: (-0.9971, 0.1255, -7.8284)
Sphere center: (0, 0, 8) (radius is 1)

After subtracting, I get a vector where the z value is -15.8284. This seems wrong to me; but I do not know what is causing it. Would a z value of -15.8284 not imply that the sphere center and the hit position are ~16 units away from each other in the z plane? Obviously these two numbers are within 1 from each other in absolute value terms, that's what leads me to think my problem has something to do with this.

Here's the main ray-tracing loop:

```
auto origin = Position3f(0, 0, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < numPixX; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numPixY; j++)
    {
        for (SceneSurface* object : objects)
        {
            float imgPlane_u = left + (right - left) * (i + 0.5f) / numPixX;
            float imgPlane_v = bottom + (top - bottom) * (j + 0.5f) / numPixY;

            Vector3f direction = (w.negated() * focal_length) + (u * imgPlane_u) + (v * imgPlane_v);

            Ray viewingRay(origin, eye, direction);

            RayTestResult testResult = object->TestViewRay(viewingRay);

            if (testResult.m_bRayHit)
            {
                Position3f hitPoint = (origin + (direction) * testResult.m_fDist);//.negated();

                Vector3f light_direction = (light - hitPoint).toVector().normalized();
                Vector3f view_direction = direction.negated().normalized();
                Vector3f surface_normal = object->GetNormalAt(hitPoint);

                image[j][i] = object->color * intensity * fmax(0, surface_normal * light_direction);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GetNormalAt is simply:

```
Vector3f Sphere::GetNormalAt(Position3f &surface)
{
    return (surface - position).toVector().normalized();
}
```

My spheres are positioned at (0, 0, 8) and (-1.5, -1, 6) with rad 1.0f.
My light is at (-3, -3, 0) with an intensity of 1.0f;

I ignore any intersection where *t* is not greater than 0 so I do not believe that is causing this problem.

I think I may be doing some kind of mistake when it comes to keeping positions and vectors in the same coordinate system (same transform?), but I'm still learning and admittedly don't understand that very well. If the view direction is always in the -*w* direction, why do we position scene objects in the positive *w* direction?

Any help or wisdom is greatly appreciated. I'm teaching this all to myself so far and I'm pleased with how much I've taken in, but something in my gut tells me this is a relatively simple mistake.

Just in case it is of any use, here's the TestViewRay function:

```
RayTestResult Sphere::TestViewRay(Ray &viewRay)
{
RayTestResult result;

result.m_bRayHit = false;

Position3f &c = position;
float r = radius;
Vector3f &d = viewRay.getDirection();
Position3f &e = viewRay.getPosition();

float part = d*(e - c);
Position3f part2 = (e - c);
float part3 = d * d;
float discriminant = ((part*part) - (part3)*((part2*part2) - (r * r)));

if (discriminant > 0)
{
    float t_add = ((d) * (part2)+sqrt(discriminant)) / (part3);
    float t_sub = ((d) * (part2)-sqrt(discriminant)) / (part3);

    float t = fmin(t_add, t_sub);

    if (t > 0)
    {
        result.m_iNumberOfSolutions = 2;
        result.m_bRayHit = true;
        result.m_fDist = t;
    }
}
else if (discriminant == 0)
{
    float t_add = ((d)* (part2)+sqrt(discriminant)) / (part3);
    float t_sub = ((d)* (part2)-sqrt(discriminant)) / (part3);

    float t = fmin(t_add, t_sub);

    if (t > 0)
    {
        result.m_iNumberOfSolutions = 1;
        result.m_bRayHit = true;
        result.m_fDist = t;
    }
}

return result;
}
```

EDIT:

I'm happy to report I figured out my problem.

Upon sitting down with my sister to look at this I noticed in my ray-sphere hit detection I had this:

```
float t_add = ((d) * (part2)+sqrt(discriminant)) / (part3);
```

Which is incorrect. *d* should be negative. It should be:

```
float t_add = ((neg_d * (e_min_c)) + sqrt(discriminant)) / (part2);
```

(I renamed a couple variables) Previously I had a zero'd vector so I could express -*d* as (zero_vector - *d*)and I had removed that because I implemented a member function to negate any given vector; but I forgot to go back and call it on *d*. After fixing that and moving my sphere's into the negative z plane my Lambertian and Blinn-Phong shading implementations work correctly.

[Lambertian + Blinn-Phong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er29A.png)

Comment: Try to multiply your surface normal by inverse radius. `((surface - position) * (1.0 / sphere_radius)).toVector().normalized();`

Comment: It looks to me like you have a typing problem - subtracting two points gives you a vector, not a point.

Comment: I went through and corrected the Position - Position returning a Position, now it returns a Vector. I was always converting the Position returned into a vector by just copying over the x, y, z values though, so I don't think anything changed.  And the radius of my Spheres is 1 for both, so multiplying by 1 / 1 wouldn't affect anything either.